# Creating Application scope as singleton in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

**In `Dagger2` while using `java` I create the `application scope` and use as `singleton` as below**

```
@Scope
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)
public @interface MyApplicationScope {
}
```

***Question :*** *`Now how to write the similar code in Kotlin`*

**What I tried**:

```
@Scope
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
annotation class ApplicationScope
```

I don't get the option `.CLASS`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Kotlin equivalent to Java's [`RetentionPolicy.CLASS`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/RetentionPolicy.html#CLASS) is [`AnnotationRetention.BINARY`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.annotation/-annotation-retention/-b-i-n-a-r-y.html).  Both refer to annotations that need to be retained in the JAR or other compiler output file, but do not need to be available at runtime.